# Is there any way to pass Properties to an Oracle datasource in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion

So I have an issue trying to get N-datatypes (`NVarchar`, NClob) to work with ColdFusion ORM using a database which has a default characterset of `US7ASCII` and an NLS characterset of `AL16UTF16`.

Essentially, this is solved either by using `setFormOfUse()` on the Connection, by setting a JVM System Property (`-Doracle.jdbc.defaultNChar=true`), or by passing that Property along when creating the Connection.

ColdFusion has a spot for adding *Connection String* attributes, which would work with MySQL, MSSQL, etc., however the Oracle JDBC driver ignores that string and only accepts a Java Properties object (see: [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html)).

Is there any way to pass a Properties object to ColdFusion's datasources?

(Unfortunately, setting the global System Property isn't an option, and I'm not sure how to make ColdFusion ORM/Hibernate account for `setFormOfUse()`, assuming that's even possible.)